# Statistics and the addition rule.

Tags: probability, statistics

i dont get why 2/3*2/3 is not 4/6... plus if i am to use the addition rule, it will be 2/3+2/3 -(The correct answer)  what will that be then?

The question was.P((3 or 5 on the first toss of a die) or (3 or 5 on the second toss of a die)) and i seem to be getting stuck.

Comment: A dice has 6 possible results, so why are you dividing your probabilities by $3$ instead of $6$?

Comment: Your post is very confusing.  The answer to the probability question you pose is (assuming I have understood it correctly) $\frac 26+\frac 26-\frac 4{36}$ since the sum double counts the cases where both tosses have satisfactory outcomes.

Comment: @Titi $\frac{2}{3}\cdot \frac{2}{3}=\frac{4}{9}$ , $\frac{2}{3}+\frac{2}{3}=\frac{4}{3}$ , but the sum is only the correct probability if the events cannot occur both. The product is only the correct probability if the events are statistically independent.

Comment: @Peter  Didn't say equal.  I wrote the probability that the first  toss is good, plus the probability that the second toss is good minus the probability that both are good.

Comment: So this is the angle i worked from...

Comment: So this is the angle i worked from..There are six possible outcomes if we roll a fair dice. 
 

so event of P (not getting a 3 or a 5) = 2/3

So, the P (not getting a 3 or a 5) on the second toss will also be=2/3

Multiply both outcomes 2/3*2/3 which gives you the P ((not getting a 3 or a 5)

2/3*2/3=4/6

Comment: @lulu Sorry, read it as an equal-sign.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

$$
\frac 2 3 \times \frac 2 3 = \frac {2\times2}{3\times3} = \frac 4 9.
$$

The probability of $3$ or $5$ on the first trial is $1/3.$

The probability that that happens on the first toss **or** the second is *not* $\frac 1 3 + \frac 1 3$ because those two events are not mutually exclusive: they could both happen.

One way to find the probability that one of these or the other (or both) occurs is to find the probability that they both fail to occur. The probability that the first one fails is $2/3$ and the probability that the second one fails is $2/3.$ The probability that the first one fails **and** the second one fails is $\frac 2 3 \times \frac 2 3 = \frac 4 9.$ Therefore the probability that you don't get two failures, i.e. that you do get at least one success, is $1- \frac 4 9 = \frac 5 9.$